# JavaFX Task not updating ProgressBar

Tags: javafx, task

My software has a button that has a heavy onAction ActionEvent.
i'm trying to update a progressBar inside this ActionEvent with a custom Task.
But the progress bar are only updating after the ActionEvent end completely.

As my software is a large project (~8000 lines) I will try to summarize the code as much as possible:

This is my custom Task:

public class VolumeProgressTask extends Task {

```
private final Volume volume;

 public VolumeProgressTask (Volume volume) {
     this.volume = volume;
 }

@Override
protected Void call() {
    double startingProgress = this.volume.getWindow().getLeftArea().getSeriesTab().getActualProgress();
    double readerProgress = 0;
    double actualProgress = 0;
    do {
        if (readerProgress != this.volume.getReader().getProgress()) {
            readerProgress = this.volume.getReader().getProgress();
            actualProgress = startingProgress + (readerProgress * this.volume.getLayers().size());
            updateProgress(actualProgress, this.volume.getWindow().getLeftArea().getSeriesTab().getMaxProgress());
        }
    } while (readerProgress < 1);
    this.volume.getWindow().getLeftArea().getSeriesTab().setActualProgress(actualProgress);
    return null;
    }
}
```

I have already ensured that the console is printing the correct percentage within the Task.

[image]

This is the ActionEvent triggered by the button which I spoke of:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> openFolderClickAction = (event) -> {
        try {
            String dicomSeriesFolderPath = LocalLoaderUtils.selectFolder(this.window.getStage());
            new Volume(dicomSeriesFolderPath, this.window);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
```

the relevant part of Volume class:

```
VolumeProgressTask task = new VolumeProgressTask(this);
Platform.runLater(() -> this.window.getLeftArea().getSeriesTab().getProgressBar().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty()));
Thread progressTaskThread = new Thread(task);
progressTaskThread.setDaemon(true);
progressTaskThread.start();
```

finally, the SeriesTab class that contains the ProgressBar:

```
@Getter private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
@Getter @Setter private double actualProgress;
@Getter @Setter private double maxProgress;
```

Thank you for reading this far.

**edit:** here is a minimal reproducible example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class MRE extends Application {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btn;

    private double count = 0;
    private final long max = 1000000;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);

        stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage.setWidth(120);
        stage.setHeight(120);
        stage.setTitle("minimal reproducible example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        this.btn = new Button();
        this.btn.setPrefHeight(25);
        this.btn.setPrefWidth(100);
        this.btn.setTranslateX(10);
        this.btn.setTranslateY(10);
        this.btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            btnAction(this);
            this.count = 0;
        });
        this.btn.setText("run actionEvent");
        group.getChildren().add(this.btn);

        this.progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        this.progressBar.setTranslateX(10);
        this.progressBar.setTranslateY(45);
        this.progressBar.setPrefHeight(25);
        this.progressBar.setPrefWidth(100);
        group.getChildren().add(this.progressBar);

    }

    public void btnAction (MRE MREObj) {
        TestTask task = new TestTask(this);
        MREObj.getProgressBar().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
        taskThread.setDaemon(true);
        taskThread.start();
        for (int i = 1; i <= this.max; i++) {
            System.out.println("hi");
            this.count++;
        }
    }

}

class TestTask extends Task<Void> {

    private final MRE MREObj;

    public TestTask (MRE MREObj) {
        this.MREObj = MREObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call () {
        double actualProgress = 0;
        double newProgress;
        do {
            newProgress = this.MREObj.getCount();
            if (newProgress != actualProgress) {
                actualProgress = newProgress;
                updateProgress(actualProgress, this.MREObj.getMax());
                System.out.println("progress: " + (actualProgress/this.MREObj.getMax()));
            }
        } while(this.MREObj.getCount() < this.MREObj.getMax());
        updateProgress(this.MREObj.getMax(), this.MREObj.getMax());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't `join` the task thread.  That will block any thread that is doing the joining.  If that thread is the JavaFX app thread (not clear from your question, but likely), it will block all the UI (including the progress bar updates), until the task is complete, it can also deadlock.  If you still have issues provide a [mcve].  A complete, custom-made minimal example that replicates the problem through copy and paste with no change or addition.  The use Lombok in a JavaFX app is not recommended by JavaFX experts like James_D (don't use it if you produce a mre).

Comment: i removed the task join but the problem persists. 
I'm also doing another join within the ActionEvent flow.

The flow is basically:

button action -> ActionEvent thread -> starts 2 threads (task and reader) -> end.

The reader thread is the hardwork, from there i extract the progress, i require to join it in execution.

Comment: "_i require to join it_" – GUI applications naturally lend themselves to [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). You don't _wait_ for task to complete. You _react_ to a task completing. In other words, do not `join` a thread. As this is a JavaFX application, you should be using something like a `Task` for background work. If you have a `Task`, then you can add an `onSucceeded` handler to the task where, in that handler, you do what needs to be done in response to the task succeeding.

Comment: *”  I'm also doing another join within the ActionEvent flow.”*. Fairly obviously, the other call to `join` will have the same effect; it will prevent any updates to the UI (including updating the progress bar) until the background task is complete. You **must not** make blocking calls on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: There’s basically no point in using a background thread at all if you call `progressTaskThread.join()` immediately after `progressTaskThread.start()`. The effect is essentially the same as running whatever code in `progressTaskThread` on the current thread.

Comment: Ok, turns out it became a mess because I was trying solution after solution without deleting code (hoping the old code would be useful). Now I cleaned it up and managed to remove the joins, the flow was simplified: button action -> ActionEvent thread -> start task -> end. But the UI still doesn't update, i'm doing the bind, there's nothing blocking the code, the progress bar stays at -1 until the end of the ActionEvent when it suddenly jumps to 1.

Comment: I will make de minimal reproducible example

Comment: *"the progress bar stays at -1 until the end of the ActionEvent"*. Yes, of course. The event handler is executed on the FX Application Thread, which is the same thread that renders the UI. No rendering can be performed until the event handler completes. You say *"there's nothing blocking the code"*, but if nothing is blocking then the event handler would terminate immediately. So *"until the end of the ActionEvent" contradicts the "nothing blocking the code" statement.

Comment: In the MRE (which needs to be posted in the question, not as an answer as it does not answer the question) you have a long-running `for` loop in the event handler. The UI cannot be updated until that `for` loop completes, so the `for` loop is blocking the FX Application Thread, preventing the progress bar values from being displayed. Again, you **must not** block the FX Application Thread. Note there are numerous other errors in that code (the most obvious being race conditions on the `count` variable).

Comment: The software performs heavy computational tasks, that can take up to a minute, the for loop just simulate this. It reads very large files to create a image in memory.

Comment: *"The software performs heavy computational tasks, that can take up to a minute, the for loop just simulate this."* Then that work should be done on a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is execute all the ActionEvent code inside a new thread, if this new thread changes something in the UI, it should be done with Platform.runLater

The ActionEvent is executed in JavaFX Main thread.
As my software performed heavy computational tasks, it would freeze this thread and no UI updates would work until the task was completed.

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> openFolderClickAction = (event) -> {
        String dicomSeriesFolderPath;
        try {
            dicomSeriesFolderPath = LocalLoaderUtils.selectFolder(this.window.getStage());
            this.window.getLeftArea().changeLeftAreaTab(LeftAreaTab.SERIES);
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    new Volume(dicomSeriesFolderPath, this.window);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                this.window.getViewportArea().notifyListeners();
            });
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.window.getLeftArea().changeLeftAreaTab(LeftAreaTab.NULL);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You should only access the scene graph on the FX Application Thread. It looks like `this.window.getLeftArea()` accesses part of the scene graph, and `this.window.getViewportArea().notifyListeners()` may update it. Both of these should not be done from a background thread. Use `Platform.runLater()` to execute that code. (If `notifyListeners()` involves long-running processes, then it should launch in a background thread.) Consider also a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)